# Box Detecting Collision with border but not resetting in a certain location?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want the char to re spawn 10px on the X axis and 10px on the Y axis when the char hits the border of the screen but it is not working.
Here is the code i'm using:

```
       if($('#char').offset().top < 0 || $('#char').offset().top > window.innerHeight || $('#char').offset().left < 0 || $('#char').offset().left > window.innerWidth ){
     console.log('Off Screen');
     left = 10;
     var reLeft = {'left':left + "px"};
     $('#char').css(reLeft);
     top = 10;
     var reTop = {'top':top + "px"};
     $('#char').css(reTop);
     }
```

*Note: If you want to look at the full code to see if I did something wrong there, you can go to [My Site](http://torin.eschweb.com/box-game.html) and press Ctrl + U*

Answer (score 0):

i dont really know if it work because i cant test it. But this is how i would do it

```
$("#char").parent().css({position: 'relative'});
$("#char").css({top: 10, left: 10, position:'absolute'});
```

Comment: I meant when it hits the edge of the screen there is no border. The code I am using does detect collision but it does not make the position of the char 10,10

Comment: i understand the question. Do you tried out my code? Maybe it is a problem with the position... A JS fiddle would be helpful...

Comment: So the position works but then the text goes away If you go here view-source:http://torin.eschweb.com/box-game.html and look at lines 44, 56, 63 thats all main parts in the code that have things for text can you tell me why they are deleting?